# printer connected event

Tags: c#, printers

I am designing an app which needs to identify if printer is connected or not. I know the methods by WMI to enumerate connected printers. But what is to be done if printer connected after application start up? Do we got any events or APIs for that? Or I have to check frequently using WMI code?

for simplicity I tried `LocalPrintServer` class like this :

```
PrintQueue printQueue = null;

            LocalPrintServer localPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();

            // Retrieving collection of local printer on user machine
            PrintQueueCollection localPrinterCollection =
                localPrintServer.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });

            System.Collections.IEnumerator localPrinterEnumerator =
                localPrinterCollection.GetEnumerator();

            while(localPrinterEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                // Get PrintQueue from first available printer
                printQueue = (PrintQueue)localPrinterEnumerator.Current;                       

                if (!printQueue.IsOffline)
                {

                    string s = "Printer found " + printQueue.FullName.ToString();
                    listBox1.Items.Add(s);
                    bDeviceFound = true;
                    button1.Enabled = bDeviceFound;


                }
```

You knows it will show the installed printers it runs on application startup. The problem is it cant identify if a printer connected after application start up.If we have any events for that,I could call this method to re-enumerate printer unless am I supposed for a thread or while loop ??

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried _anything_? Show your work..

Comment: I can't directly help you but try google for any blog entries / code by Duncan Edwards Jones. He seems to be the proper .net-printing guru.

Comment: I'd start from a BackgroundWorker which would keep polling the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue by setting a timer to pull details .